# Trying to prove $p,p \to (r \to q) \vdash (\neg q \to \neg r)$ by using natural deduction.

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, natural-deduction

Inference rules allowed are: $\lor$, $\wedge$, $\rightarrow$, $\neg$ introductions and eliminations.

In question, it says I am allowed to make use of a lemma or equivalence as long as I provide a proof of it by natural deduction too. (I will come to that soon enough, hopefully.)

First of all, that "$,$" between $p$ and $p \rightarrow (r \rightarrow q)$ made me a bit confused, but I ended up assuming that comma just splits two premises we are given. I tried to not dig too much and proceeded to make proof, however I got stuck after using implication elimination on $p \rightarrow (r \rightarrow q)$ and obtaining $(r \rightarrow q)$. From there on, I have a sense that I will just use 4-5 more steps and reach $(\neg q \to \neg r)$ but I just couldn't figure it out.

Then I realized that I can make use of equation $p \rightarrow q \equiv \neg p \lor q $ .

As stated in question, I tried to prove this equation by natural deduction (I know at this point I am just making things harder than it is supposed to be, but what the heck..)

This is the proof I tried to make in fitch style:

[Proof 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFSFr.jpg)

If you realize I am using double negation here and I am not even sure if that is even allowed to use.

From here, I just needed to show that $(r \rightarrow q) \equiv (\neg q \rightarrow r)$ knowing $(\neg r \lor q) \equiv (\neg \neg q \lor \neg r)$ and that is $(\neg r \lor q) \equiv (q \lor \neg r)$

But if you realize, that means I will have to prove double negation law "$\neg \neg q \equiv q$" as well as commutative law "$(\neg r \lor q) \equiv (q \lor \neg r)$". Like these extra two small proofs are not enough, I also have to use them with proper notation/syntax in latex aside with fitch style proof tables.

This makes me realize that it is definitely a bad idea to make this proof by natural deduction using these "transformation" equivalences if I may call them that.

So, I think I need to give up on that idea and stick to direct proof with implications.

However, as stated above, I am stuck after implication elimination. Could you guys help me figure it out how to move forward from there?

P.S: Reason I state all those unnecessary steps is that, I think it is just more appropriate to not just "ask for a direct answer" but provide my thought process. Another challenge of doing this proof for me is that having to use fitch style proofs in latex. I just can't figure out where to place that "p" before comma in the question. Anyway, enough confusion!

Comment: @Arthur This is natural deduction, not binary logic.

Comment: Different authors use different axioms for $\lnot$ and $\bot$ in natural deduction.  It would help to list yours explicitly.

Comment: The ',' is indeed merely to separate between different statements. So you have 2 premises and 1 conclusion. But we will need to know how the rules for Negation Introduction and Conditional Introduction are defined in the system you use before we can tell you how to do the proof. Also, does your system make use of a $\bot$?

Comment: what is the meaning of $\vdash$ ?

Comment: @Anonymous $\vdash$ is entailment.  From a logical point of view, $A \vdash B$ means $B$ is provable from $A$.  From a programming point of view, $A \vdash B$ means "if $A$ is in theory, then $B$ can be added to the theory".

Comment: $\Gamma \vdash \phi$ means that statement $\phi$ can be derived from the set of statements $\Gamma$.  Of course, whether it can be derived or not really depends on what derivation rules you have or don't have, so you really should say something like $\Gamma \vdash_S \phi$ to say that $\phi$ can be derived from $\Gamma$ using the formal proof system $S$. But since we typically assume that we are using a sound and complete proof system, we drop the $S$.

Comment: I don't have detailed information regarding rules for Negation Introduction and Conditional Introduction in the system we use. All it says in the question that we are allowed and, or, negate and implies intro/eliminations. However, I can say that $\bot$ introduction on your answer below is not allowed (@Bram28)

Comment: @Bonellia Well, not being given the exact rules that you can use, and yet being asked to give an exact proof makes it kind of hard, doesn't it? :)  Anyway, if you don;t have $\bot$, you probably need to do 2 subproofs: one where you derive $q$ from $r$, and one where you derive $\neg q$ from $r$. You can then point to those two subproofs and say $\neg r$.  Some systems have that as their formal implementation of the Proof by Contradiction reasoning technique.

Comment: @Bonellia Are your rules $\{x,~\lnot x\} \vdash y$ for $\lnot$ elim and $\{x \vdash y,~ x \vdash \lnot y\} \vdash \lnot x$ for $\lnot$ intro?

Comment: does $\vdash$ have an equivalence with the operators of prepositional logic? I mean can it be expressed as a combination of these operators? could it be interpreted as $\equiv$

Comment: @Anonymous No and no.

Comment: @Anonymous No, absolutely not!! You are mixing logical operators with metalogical expressions *about* statements that involve logical operators!

Comment: oh I see, thank you :)

Comment: @DanielIV Our reference book shows something similar to what you ask. http://i.imgur.com/0Lk0sS5.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Fitch system that I use, the proof is below. But again, your rules may be defined differently!

[image]

Comment: This is proof by contradiction, am I right? Also thanks. (Which "editor" is that you are using btw?)

Comment: Yes, the $\neg$ Intro rule shows that the assumption of $R$ leads to a contradiction, so $R$ is not true.  The $\neg$ Intro thus formalizes the Proof by Contradiction kind of reasoning.  I use a program called Fitch, which is part of a software package that comes with the book "Language, Proof, and Logic"

Comment: This isn't proof by contradiction.  Proof by contradiction requires double negation elimination.  Proof by contradiction is $(\lnot C \vdash \bot) \vdash C$, this is $(C \vdash \bot) \vdash \lnot C$.

Comment: There is a problem in this proof by the way, which is using "$\bot$ Intro". This is not allowed. Trying to find a workaround myself atm :/

Comment: @Bonellia It is allowed in the system *I* use (notice all the checkmarks :) ) ... but like I said, the system *you* use maybe different. So, again, what are *your* rules?

Comment: @DanielV Conceptually, both are instances of Proof by Contradiction.  But syntactically, your system may indeed only allow one form, and not the other,

Comment: @Bram28 if by system you mean is fitch, yes we use that system. Only reason I said "$\bot$ intro" shouldn't be used is, on question it says:"Prove the following claim by natural deduction. Use only the natural deduction rules $\wedge$,$\lor$,$\rightarrow$,$\neg$ introduction and elimination. If you attempt to make use of a lemma or equivalence, you need to prove it by
natural deduction too."

Comment: @Bonellia But there are different variants of Fitch-style systems, so that still doesn't tell me exactly what rules you have.  And in the variant that I have, I know that I cannot derive $\neg  q \rightarrow \neg r$ from $r \rightarrow q$ without the $\bot$ Introduction rule.

Comment: I will try to do subproofs @Bram28 suggested. Rules are summarized as follows in our reference book: http://i.imgur.com/0Lk0sS5.jpg

Comment: That's interesting.  My system actually has those *exact* same rules, except what your system labels as $\neg$ Elimination, my system calls $\bot$ Introduction, while the $\neg$ Elimination in my system is what your system considers a $\neg \neg$ Elimination rule.

Comment: In fact, I think that you can just leave my original proof as is: you just need to make sure that on line 7 you say that you use $\neg$ Elim instead of $\bot$ Intro. Since you were allowed to use the 'rules for Negation', that should be fine!

Comment: @Bram28 Bingo! See this latex error I have and also what our pdf about fitch style shows on the right. There is no Bottom elimination thus i have an error on fitch style latex macro: http://i.imgur.com/Y5YdPOb.jpg

Comment: @Bonellia  So it looks like there is a mismatch between the labels of your system and the ones of the fitch macro as well ... What if you try \bi (for bottom introduction) in your macro?

Comment: As seen on screenshot, it gives an error "undefined control sequence" referring bottom intro not defined. But when I change it to /ne it works: http://i.imgur.com/o918urx.jpg Btw it says "avoid extended discussions in comments." Shall we move to chat if you don't mind? I want rest of the discussion to be relevant to everyone checking question/answer :) (I can't start chat due to low reputation it seems)

Comment: Ah!  So it looks like you got it all ok then!

Answer (score 1):

First, the theorem doesn't have any $\land$ or $\lor$ in it, so you won't need any inference using those (unless your negation rules are defined in terms of $\land$, some authors do that and it's a bit annoying).

Second, proving

$$p,~p\to(r \to q) \vdash \lnot q \to \lnot r$$

is the same as proving

$$p,~p\to(r \to q),~\lnot q \vdash \lnot r$$

And then applying $\implies$ introduction to move the $\lnot q$ to the right.

Try proving:

$$p,~p\to(r \to q),~\lnot q,~r \vdash \bot$$

And then use your $\lnot$ introduction rule to convert the $r \vdash \bot$ deduction into $\lnot r$.  Depending on how your negation rules are set up (this isn't universal) you may be expected to prove $\dots,~r \vdash q \land \lnot q$ rather than $\dots,~r \vdash \bot$.

Comment: Sorry for the silly remark, but I think I need some sort of "English" translation to "$,$" in order to completely understand what I am trying to prove here. When I see "$\rightarrow$" I can tell "implies that" or when I see "$\vdash$" I can tell "x ⊢ y means y is provable from x" (with words used specifically in wikipedia) or just say "therefore". But that comma doesn't translate to anything in my mind. What would you come up with to explain meaning of that ","? I tried to check my books, pdfs, notes etc but since it is a single character, I can't really refer to it, so searches fail.

Comment: @Bonellia Comma is used to indicate multiple statements.  So $a,~b\vdash c,~d$ means "the two statements, $c$, $d$, are provable from the two statements, $a$, $b$".